# Layered window: Why's the edge rounded automatically?

Tags: c++, winapi, rounded-corners

I am trying to draw a `hbitmap` with a `layeredwindow` directly onto the screen. this also works now how it should, yet the left upper corner of the image is *always* rounded.

I'm creating the window with:

```
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        , szWindowClass, 0, 
        WS_VISIBLE
        , 150,250, width, height, 0, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

Could anyone help me please to solve this problem?

Comment: What OS version you are using?

Comment: Oh Windows 7 Professional with Aero. Is that the reason?

Comment: I've disabled aero and the result is the same..

Comment: Here: http://i.imgur.com/iKaVd.png
It's originally a black rectangle with identical corners...
This is really an unusual problem? because I really cannot imagine what's causing that sicne I used pretty basical stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `WS_VISIBLE` as the window style, which is equivalent to `WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE`.  Overlapped windows have rounded corners at the top.

Use `WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE` instead.